# Log in expiration Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just read codes from a tutorial regarding the 'remember user token' function.

```
cookies[:remember_token] = { value:   remember_token,
                             expires: 20.years.from_now.utc }
```

I am wondering that whether this 'expires' above controls how long the user is in the logged in status. And if I set it to, say, 20 minutes, would the user be logged out automatically logged out? I am not sure if they are related.

Comment: The easiest way to test this and answer your question is to set it to 1 minute and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you could change the year to week,minute